# how to get the text in a context menu item which is added in the run time?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have created a contextmenu in a wpf form.And menu items are added in the run time.
following is the XAML code snippet to add the context menu:

```
 <Window.ContextMenu>        
 <ContextMenu AllowDrop="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Opened="note_Opened" >
 <MenuItem Header="View Notes" Click="MenuItemViewNotes_Click"  Name="mainMenu" />
  ...............................       
</ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

menu items are added as following:

```
private void note_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {       
......... //some codes goes here   
            while(reader.Read()){ 

                MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem();
                newItem.Header = textEncrypt.DecryptString(reader[2].ToString());
               // newItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MenuItemViewNotes_Click);

                mainMenu.Items.Add(newItem);

                                }
        }


    }
```

following is the "MenuItemViewNotes_Click" methods .I want to get the coresponding index of the clicked menu item.But I was unable to give name or index when I adding the item in the above method.Is there any way to do that?

```
private void MenuItemViewNotes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {        
  mainMenu.Items.Clear();
            MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;

            if (mi!= null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(mi.Header.ToString());

            }            
    }
```

here I didn't get any out put.I think it may be some thing wrong in even handling.

again following is the xaml code where call to the   "note_opend " and "MainItemViewNotes_click" functions

```
<ContextMenu AllowDrop="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Opened="note_Opened" >
        <MenuItem Header="View Notes"   Name="mainMenu"  >
            <MenuItem Header="note1" Click="MenuItemViewNotes_Click"  IsCheckable="True"/>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="Settings" Click="MenuItemSettings_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="MenuItemClose_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

have u tried to check e.Source or e.OriginalSource?  you might need to debug to see the type, but for RoutedEvents like above, they should contain the source that you are after

Comment: Yes I tried this e.Source and e.OriginalSource.But they gave me the same count to each menu item.I need to get different count or index to different menu items that added at the run time.